# Graphics for iPhone development from Maya

Tags: iphone, maya

I am new to integrating graphics into iPhone apps and need some direction on integrating graphics from maya into the application flow. Does anyone out there have any advice on good books or tutorials covering the design flow for Maya -> iPhone SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 3D Programming by O'Reilly is a great place to start. That's what I used to get going anyway.

#### EDIT:

Also, you can check out my post on this thread:

[getting-a-maya-model-into-the-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675475/getting-a-maya-model-into-the-iphone/5119197#5119197)