# solutions for viewing and using 3d models and file types in android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

Ive seen a bunch of opensource solutions but I cant say any of them seem to be trouble free and easy to use.

I was hopping to get some input from the community here on anyones experience with getting 3d files like obj or 3ds or others to display properly and what types of solutions they came up with.

Ive found some things like min3d and some others but also have seen in some other forums that with the 3.0 update that there is easier ways to get 3d to work but i havent had the time to research it.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AssImp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I took a look at that.....from the notes i read it looks like i could use some python to get it to work with android. Thanks for the link it definitely helps to see some new solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get a basic OpenGL-ES project up, then use the basic rendering functions in your render loop to draw your geometry. Should be fairly similar to my post here: [[Getting a Maya Model into the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675475/getting-a-maya-model-into-the-iphone/5119197#5119197)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675475/getting-a-maya-model-into-the-iphone/5119197#5119197) Or one of the other posters suggestions in that thread.